# Flutter_Webview showing blank screen

Tags: flutter

i tried to use the Flutter_webview library, But i can't seem to get it to work. All i see is blank screen and in the Debug i see Asynchronous suspension
Can anyone help me what could be the issue?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class NewPageClicked extends StatelessWidget {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the debug console

```
E/flutter (31283): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
E/flutter (31283): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
E/flutter (31283): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31283): #2      TextureAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage
package:flutter/…/services/platform_views.dart:1043
E/flutter (31283): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31283): #3      AndroidViewController.create
package:flutter/…/services/platform_views.dart:748
E/flutter (31283): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31283): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView
package:flutter/…/rendering/platform_view.dart:193
E/flutter (31283): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31283):
```

Comment: have you tried on release mode?! Real device or emulator?! Version of Android or iOS?! Some may need extra details to make it work.

Comment: I tried it on Android Emulator...